# How to delete ALL Cookies from windows phone WebBrowser control

Tags: windows-phone-7, cookies

In my app I use WebBrowser control. User can visit http://mail.google.com then without logging out from google.com he visits http://twitter.com then http://abcd.com etc.

Now my requirement is to do the fresh start of the WebBrowser control and revisit those website and force the user to login again on those sites.

How can I **clear ALL Cookies** from windows phone WebBrowser control in WP7? I tried few  JavaScript examples available in net. Nothing worked. Can you anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

the control is not to give you that fine grained control over cookies etc. it is meant to be use to display html data.

since a given instance of webbrowser control would cache data in given session, I'd suggest you either create new instance either by redirecting user to that page or doing so onclick etc

Comment: I tried creating new instance of webbrowser control but it didn't work. Old user was still logged in http://mail.google.com. I guess all instances of WebBrowser control share common file for storing cookies..Am I right?

Comment: say you navigate back (if to previous xaml page) and then you went forward back to page with webbrowser control, does it still have same issue ?

Comment: don't think there's anything else you can do